# how to select a li which is nested within another ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs

(please do not update the english grammer in this question/ I wont be able to approve it and this question wont get resolved.)

This is my UI

[image]

It contains various li elements whose values are populated using this angular html

```
<div class="row">
            <li class="no-bullet-li li-12 monaco-font"> {{selectedChangeEligibilityPlan}}</li>

            <ul class="ul-plan-1">
                <li class="no-bullet-li"  ng-repeat="plan in fewThings">
                    <div ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': $index == selectedIndex }" ng-click="itemClicked($index)" class="li-alt monaco-font"> p2|{{plan.planName}} | {{plan.planId}}
                        <a class="iconing-sub" ng-click="addClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                        <a ng-click="deleteClick(item)" ng-class="{ active : active.one }" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove iconing_1-sub"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="ul-plan">
                        <li  class="no-bullet-li li-8 monaco" ng-repeat="item in plan.planIds">
                            p1| {{ plan.planNames[$index]}} | {{item}}
                            <a <a ng-click="editClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil iconing"></i></a>
                            <a ng-click="deleteClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove iconing_1"></i></a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

It uses the nested ng-repeat.

The whole UI is contained within a one controller ( no directives used) 
 the following code gets triggered when someone clicks the blue lis.

```
 $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
    console.log($index);
    // console.log($(item).closest('li') );
    $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
  };
```

here's how to ui looks and its great.

[image]

problem arises when I try to do the same logic for the pink ones (nested ng-repeat li). It selects other pink lis in all the other stack too.

here's the screenshot. 
[image]

second part of question:

I have I have the above UI plus I also have this second UI that is loaded along with this on the same page. It contains a bunch of horizontal rows.

Once the user click the blue pink colored lis it goes into the active state. Then the user can click the row which he likes. upon clicking it the plan name of currently selected li will get replaced.

Here is the html for it.

```
    <div class="row">
        <li class="no-bullet-li li-12 monaco-font"> {{selectedChangeEligibilityPlan}}</li>

        <ul class="ul-plan-1">
            <li class="no-bullet-li"  ng-repeat="plan in fewThings">
                <div class="li-alt monaco-font"> p2|{{plan.planName}} | {{plan.planId}}
                    <a class="iconing-sub" ng-click="addClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                    <a ng-click="deleteClick(item)" ng-class="{ active : active.one }" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove iconing_1-sub"></i></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="ul-plan">
                    <li ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': $index == selectedIndex }" ng-click="itemClicked($index)"  class="no-bullet-li li-8 monaco" ng-repeat="item in plan.planIds">
                        p1| {{ plan.planNames[$index]}} | {{item}}
                        <a ng-click="editClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil iconing"></i></a>
                        <a ng-click="deleteClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove iconing_1"></i></a>

                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see in your code how the pink `li`s get selected, they don't appear to have an `ng-click` on them or the `ng-class` to make them selected. A plunker or jsFiddle showing the problem would be helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to save the state of the data (which one is selected) inside your controller using `$index`. The `$index` property isn't unique among different `ng-repeats`, so when  you set your `$scope.selectedIndex` to `$index`, each of your sub lists will see that their `$index` matches, and so will each trigger the `ng-class` and add the `selected-class-name` class.

What you could do instead is have each item in the data have a unique index and use that id to store which item is selected in `$scope.selectedIndex`.

```
<ul class="ul-plan">
  <li ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': item.id == selectedIndex }" ng-click="itemClicked(item.id)" class="no-bullet-li li-8 monaco" ng-repeat="item in plan.planIds">

    p1| {{ plan.planNames[$index]}} | {{item}}
    <a ng-click="editClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil iconing"></i></a>
    <a ng-click="deleteClick(item)" href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove iconing_1"></i></a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: in console log i get  --  TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Try moving the `ng-repeat` to the first attribute of the `li`

Comment: It works for now, any help with the second part of the question ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the second part is asking, any chance you could clarify it? Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks strange.

```
 <a ng-click="select('one')" href="">
```

Did you really mean to pass a hardcoded 'one' to the function?  Or was it supposed to be the index, like the deleteClick() call.

Comment: Ok. I am wondering about your usage of the same variable names and auto variables (like $index). Each ng-repeat creates it own scope,so the $index you are using in the nested should work, but is kind of a bad practice. Take a look at this thread, stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600/…, especially the solution (and last answer) to ensure uniqueness of the $index reference.